# Is this a "bounded partial sum"?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence, summation

For $x\in (-1,1)$, is the sum

$$\left\|\sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^k |x|^{\frac{1}{k}}\right\|\le N$$

a "bounded partial sum" for all positive integers $N$?  Or is it not really actually bounded, since $N$ goes off to infinity?  I am trying to use Dirichlet's test but want to be careful and know what a bounded partial sum really means.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a bounded partial sum, since the bound $N$ grows to $\infty$ with $N$. If $x=1$ it is easy to get a bound for the partial sums independent of $N$:
$$
\Bigl|\sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^k\Bigr|=|-1+1-1+\dots\pm1|\le1.
$$

Let's see that the sums are bounded for all $x\in(0,1)$. Suppose first that $N$ is even. Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^k\,x^{1/k}=(x^{1/2}-x)+(x^{1/4}-x^{1/3})+\dots+(x^{1/N}-x^{1/(N-1)}).
$$
Lets bound each of the summands.
$$\begin{align}
x^{1/(k+1)}-x^{1/k}&=x^{1/(k+1)}\bigl(1-x^{1/(k(k+1))}\bigr)\\
&\le 1-e^{\tfrac{\log x}{k(k+1)}}\\
&\le\frac{|\log x\,|}{k(k+1)}.
\end{align}
$$
Then
$$
0\le\sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^k\,x^{1/k}\le|\log x\,|\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=|\log x\,|.
$$
If $N$ is odd, we get
$$
\Bigl|\sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^k\,x^{1/k}\Bigr|\le|\log x\,|+1.
$$
The partial sums are bounded, but not uniformly in $x$.